# Use a vue plugin in vuepress by a wrapper

Tags: vue.js, plugins, vuepress

[v-gallery Plugin](https://terryz.github.io/vue/#/gallery)

- I am trying to use this vue plugin in vuepress site
- As the documentation (for plugin) is written in vuepress and contains the plugin (v-gallery)  same is possible .
- Imported the plugin locally in singlefile component
  `import VueGallery from "v-gallery/src/Gallery";` and proceeded as default instructions in the documentation

### The issue

- The above during deploy/build throws a error window not defined ,but continues to build and deploys
- Is there a method to use the plugin globally by declaring it enhance.js (tried/failed{in build})
- Are there any other suggestions to getting it to work without the build error
- Please throw light on using vue plugin in vuepress in general

#### Tried contacting the plugin developer ,not avail

#### Tried using `import VueGallery from "v-gallery";` to import in Sfc same failed

[Link to github repo to reproduce](https://github.com/shriaviator/vuepress-project-one.git)